# Setting up an Intel VPro with AMT infrastructure

Tags: windows, remote-access, intel, remote-desktop, kvm

I'm trying to set up a remote management system with VPro supported computers under the same network. I've done a good amount of research into this topic and now i'm trying choose the right path to suit my needs. The system needs to follow certain parameters.

Parameters:

Remote KVM control without User Consent

Power on, off, control bios of selected computers

Control a network of computer within a wired internet connection

Allow remote connection from outside the network to client PCs within the network (i.e at home)

Remote AMT Configuration with Admin Controls

I understand that VPro supports all of these actions, however it's the server system that handles them. I had looked into Intel SCS Lite, however i believe this is just a configuration tool and database for the profiles and i cannot actually control client actions. Tools like Microsoft SCCM look promising, however would it fulfill all my needs? Are their cheaper alternatives? There is also Intel VPro platform solutions manager. For this option, do i create a database of the AMT PC's with intel SCS console than connect to that through the platform solutions manager so i can operate on my client PCs? Any information regarding the setup and configuration of remote management of a compute network supporting VPro would be helpful.

Edit: This was a great site i found for anyone else who is researching VPro 
http://windowsmasher.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/intel-vpro-the-basics-of-vpro/

I still welcome any additional information.

Comment: This question is not programming related, and therefore is off-topic here. You might have better luck deleting it here and asking at one of the other [se] sites, such as [sf], instead. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions. Setting up remote management is not a programming task.The [help] has more information about the types of question that are on-topic here.

Comment: There is an AMT SDK which allows developers to customize their management consoles by writing their own applications.  It wouldn't fit in Server Fault.

Answer (score 2):

Blindly assuming that you're not bound to windows solutions and regarding your parameters, I think...

> Remote KVM control without User Consent
>
> Allow remote connection from outside the network to client PCs within the network (i.e at home)

You don't really need no enterprise tool integration for this... do you?
Just set up a html page that contains links like vnc://your-client-xxx and let
[realvnc plus](https://www.realvnc.com/products/viewerplus/)
handle the rest? For the KVM/VNC-Sessions, you don't need a middleman SCCM/whatever.
VNC will connect to your AMT-enabled client directly, using TCP port 16992 (or 16993 when
using TLS which you surely want...?).

Allowing remote connection from outside has nothing to do with SCCM or vPro... You'll most likely have a VPN connection to your 'work network'? The vPro-enabled clients will (by default) share the DHCP-obtained IP with the client, so you should be able to protect vPro access by a ('real') firewall as desired.

> Power on, off, control bios of selected computers
>
> Control a network of computer within a wired internet connection

Again, no need for a paid tool. For the requirement "power on/off",
you might consider [amttool](https://wiki.debian.org/AMT/SerialOverLan), at least
for pre-AMT-9.0-systems (as 9.0 dropped the older vPro SOAP protocol EOI in favour of DASH). DASH was supported since vPro 6.0 IIRC, so you could also use
AMD's free [dashcli](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/tools-for-dmtf-dash/).
Shell tools are great for scripting (read: scheduled power management / cron) but
you surely were looking for a nice GUI tool. You may want to look at [amtc / amtc-web](https://github.com/schnoddelbotz/amtc), its demo site or github-wiki. It should be easy
to add vnc:// links to that currently power-management-focussed (fast!) webapp.

Ahh, and I never used it myself, but there's also [vTul](https://github.com/Tulpep/vTul), a PowerShell based GUI...

If it's all about really rarely power-cycling a single machine: Don't forget that vPro comes with a web-interface, which also allows to do this...

> Remote AMT Configuration with Admin Controls

As stated by ChileAddict, SCS Lite should be fine. AFAIK it will also take care
of certificate renewals for TLS-enabled clients. And you can use it to push/update
AMT configuration.

> Any information regarding the setup and configuration of remote management of a compute network supporting VPro would be helpful.

Check with your PC supplier. They can deliver your hosts with RCFG (Remote Configuration) enabled. The new clients will then send HELLO packets to your provisioner.example.com,
where example.com is taken from the DHCP reply received. The provisioner must have
a certificate installed that is accepted by AMT, see [intel's page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/remote-support/intel-vpro-certificates.html).
An alternative is to deploy configuration using USB sticks -- or by hand. Where by hand will not allow TLS-secured communications...

Comment: Ports can be 16992-16995, 5900, 623 or 664

Answer (score 0):

You have definitely done your homework and that windowsmasher site sums things up nicely. Unfortunately, the free tools, like the AMT Commander, the Platform Solution Manager, the Web UI that is part of AMT, etc are not enterprise level solutions and do not have databases to hold the information for each system in your environment.  (I think the AMT Commander uses your registry to store system information and you can connect to many systems and not have to input them every time you start it. However you can't do an operation on multiple systems, for example "shut all my systems down and apply some patch".) It's a one system at a time deal.

You can provision multiple systems using the Intel SCS and when I was last using it, there was a database involved.  I do not know much about SCCM.  There are other Enterprise-level tools such as Landesk that offer management of many systems simultaneously (not free, of course.)

If you wanted to be able to manage multiple systems at a time without purchasing the software, you would have to write your own management console using the [AMT SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-the-latest-intel-amt-software-development-kit-sdk/). (Sorry!)

You might want to look at [Meshcentral.com](http://info.meshcentral.com/) (same developer who wrote the [AMT Commander/Open Manageability Toolkit](http://opentools.homeip.net/open-manageability)) he is always adding new features and you can also download the source code.

I hope this helps.